# matplotlib basemap no module named axes_grid1

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, centos, matplotlib-basemap

i have a problem after installing Basemap 1.0.6. I'm running a virtualenv, first a activated my virtualenv, went into my home directory and downloaded the latest Basemap version. Then i installed it via pip using:

```
pip install basemap-1.0.6.tar.gz
```

all works fine. then i exported my GEOS_DIR to /usr/local/ because my libgeos_c and geos_c.h stored there.

Then i tried to run the simpletest.py in the folder /home/fv/basemap-1.0.6/examples/, after that i got the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpletest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
  File "/home/fv/virtualenv/20130426/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
ImportError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1'
```

im running centos,

i hope anyone can help me? :)

Comment: Suspect you have to upgrade (or install) your version of `matplotlib`

Comment: yeah, i have reinstalled matplotlib and basemap and now are all fills available :) thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suspect you have to upgrade (or install) your version of matplotlib.

Comment: `sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it was really a version problem. I had the same problem with basemap 1.0.7 and mpl 1.1.1rc. The strange thing is that I didn't have any problem with this combination. Then I removed my .local folder and reinstalled basemap (mpl was installed as Ubuntu package). At the end, it said:

```
Skipping installation of /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/__init__.py (namespace package)
```

But my previous installation (I backed up the old .local folder) actually had an **init**.py file. Once I copied the old file over, it worked. The contents are:

```
try:
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    pass # must not have setuptools
```

Also, the old folder had a `basemap-1.0.7.egg-info` file, while the new one had a

Comment: Note: The normal state should be that there are no `__init__.py` but only `..nspkg.pth` files.